# Align text with JSON in the middle of a column in Sharepoint online

Tags: json-formatting, json

Hey i am trying to set text vertically in the middle of a column in Sharepoint online. I found some solutions and i tryed all so far but none of them works. I wonder if the coding or naming of JSON-Code has changed since some of the solutions were 2 or 3 years old. Can somebody find the mistake?:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "display": "table",
    "width": "100%"
  },
"attributes": {
    "class": " sp-field-fontSizeSmall sp-css-color-LightGrayFont"},

   "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "div",
      "txtContent": "@currentField",
      "style": {
        "font-size": "15px",
        "display": "table-cell",
        "text-align": "center",
        "vertical-align": "middle"
      }
    }
   ]   
}
```

Comment: from me your json is still working

Comment: Thank you! Its really weird for me